# Awk for handling three files

Tags: awk

Input:

```
File 1
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
A     91    -    E    Abu    7    -
B     82    -    f    Anu    9    -       
C     93    -    G    Aru    8    -

File 2
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
A     91    -    x    Bob    7    -
B     82    -    y    Bag    9    -       
C     93    -    z    Bui    8    -

File 3
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
A     91    -    T    Can    7    -
B     82    -    U    Con    9    -       
C     93    -    V    Cuu    8    -
```

Output Expected:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
A     91  Abu  Bob  Can    
B     82  Anu  Bag  Cun           
C     93  Aru  Bui  Cuu
```

I have three files having same data at col1 and 2. I need to print fifth column of all files along with first two column.
I am able to do using two files. So Can anyone help me to do with three and more files?

Comment: When do you want to print col1 and col2? if in all three files they are equal or some other condition?

Comment: Join map page - http://linux.die.net/man/1/join

Comment: @TomRon: The `join` command can only join on one column.  While you certainly can make it work, it ain't trivial. I guess that depends, in part, on whether the join is on one or two columns, of course.  I immediately see a two-column join (on col1 and col2, and it could be a three-column join if col6 has to match too), but if it is only col1 that is joined, then `join` is easy enough to use as long as the files are in sorted order.  Of course, the question says 'col1 and col2'.

Comment: What should be the output if file 1 contains an extra line `A 78 - H Aux 7 -`?  Should `Aux` appear in the output at all, or should it be omitted?  Does the same apply to unmatched lines in file 2 and file 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `awk`:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    SUBSEP = FS;
    print "col1 col2 col3 col4 col5"
}
FNR>1 {
    a[$1,$2] = (a[$1,$2]?a[$1,$2]FS$5:$5)
}
END {
    for(x in a) print x, a[x]
}' file1 file2 file3
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
C 93 Aru Bui Cuu
A 91 Abu Bob Can
B 82 Anu Bag Con
```

You can pipe the output to `sort` if you required sorted output. This **does not** limit to three files. It is scalable to `n` number of files. Just add the file names at the end or use `*` to glob to all files under a given directory.

Comment: What happens if there is a row `A 78 - H Aux 7 -` in file 1?  The row with key A/78 will get printed even though there was no match for it in file 2 or 3.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's unclear if OP only wants to exclude printing data that is not present in all files.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all three files have same number of rows because of this sentence

> I have three files having same data at col1 and 2.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";
getline<"file1";getline<"file2";getline<"file3";
print "col1","col2","col3","col4","col5";
while(1) {getline < "file1";a=$1;b=$2;c=$5;getline<"file2";d=$5;f=getline<"file3";e=$5;
if(!f)exit;print a,b,c,d,e}}'
```

Output:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
A       91      Abu     Bob     Can
B       82      Anu     Bag     Con
C       93      Aru     Bui     Cuu
```

This will discard first line of each file, then reads files line by line, printing desired fields.